# Draw an oval shape in Jetpack Compose Koltin

Tags: kotlin, jvm, android-jetpack-compose, shapes

I want to create or draw the oval shape.

I have done as below

```
class CustomOvalShape : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(
        size: androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        density: androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
    ): Outline {
        val path = Path().apply {
            val rect = Rect(0f, 0f, size.width, size.height)
            addOval(rect)
        }
        return Outline.Generic(path)
    }
}
```

I am using jetpack compose kotlin and when I am using above class I am getting an error as below:

```
Inheritance from an interface with '@JvmDefault' members is only allowed with -Xjvm-default option
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check imports, should be `import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape`

Comment: @bylazy: `imports` are correct.

Comment: Thanks! This is working, I get an oval shape. For me, the code compiled successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draw an oval shape using Kotlin Compose as below-

```
@Composable
fun OvalShape() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        val centerX = size.width / 2
        val centerY = size.height / 2
        val radiusX = size.width / 2
        val radiusY = size.height / 2

        drawOval(
            color = Color.Blue,
            topLeft = Offset(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY),
            size = Size(radiusX * 2, radiusY * 2),
            style = Stroke(width = 2.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
}
```